Dockerfile copy fails: '"/azsh-linux-agent/start.sh" not found' during build. Why?
This is my Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:22.04

RUN apt update
RUN apt upgrade -y
RUN apt install -y curl git jq libicu70

# Also can be "linux-arm", "linux-arm64".
ENV TARGETARCH="linux-x64"

WORKDIR /azp/

COPY ./azsh-linux-agent/start.sh ./
RUN chmod +x ./start.sh

RUN useradd agent
RUN chown agent ./
USER agent
ENTRYPOINT ./start.sh

I try to build image,from pwd
/home/jh/azsh-linux-agent

I got error when I try build
docker build --tag "azsh-linux-agent:1.0" --file "./azsh-linux-agent.dockerfile" .

like this
--------------------
  10 |     WORKDIR /azp/
  11 |     
  12 | >>> COPY ./azsh-linux-agent/start.sh ./
  13 |     RUN chmod +x ./start.sh
  14 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref c6a592e2-a63c-497e-addd-2fab546c3594::hy7y7sols7kbk34sms7iylyew: "/azsh-linux-agent/start.sh": not found

why is script not detected?

If you are building from /home/jh/azsh-linux-agent, then you would need to use
COPY ./start.sh ./

... to copy the file /home/jh/azsh-linux-agent/start.sh into the Docker container. Or you could use the absolute path as in
COPY /home/jh/azsh-linux-agent/start.sh ./

